# Calling a JavaScript - It's not working...

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/).

I've got the following in the body...

```
<!--Search Start-->
<div class="search-inner">
<form onsubmit="showpell_13_14(this.efc.value); return false;">
    <input type="text" value="Enter 13-14 PELL Score" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter 13-14 PELL Score') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter 13-14 PELL Score'; }" class="search-input-bg" id="textfield"  />
    </form>
</div>
<!--Search End-->
```

You'll find this box on the top-left hand side of the site.

I'm trying to call the script using this `function showpell_13_14(efc) {` which is located in the js file. There's a link to the JS file [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/js/efccalc13-14.js).

It's not working. All it does is refresh the page.

Comment: why `this.efc.value` on submit??

Comment: What is `this.efc.value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Id for the input field does not seem very *unique*: "textfield", but if it is unique you could use it in the `onsubmit` property of the `<form>` tag like

```
<form onsubmit="showpell_13_14(document.getElementById('textfield').value); return false;">
```

That is assuming that you actually want to use the value of that input field for your calculations ...

Comment: That worked. I changed the input field to something more unique. But, take a look at it again please. Click [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/). If you open it in Chrome, the window is long (top to bottom of the screen), and really skinny. But in IE, or FF, it looks like a normal window. Any ideas on how that works?

Comment: At the end of your JavaScript code you call a `confirm` dialogue. That is a text based and very unflexible way of displaying your information (i.e. format is defined by the browser!). The confirm-dialogue is meant primarily for a short decision (OK/cancel) to be entered by the user. You could alternatively open a pop-up window (often blocked by the browser's security settings) or use a `<div>` to dsplay the information.